# Pester doesn't reflect changes in a script

Tags: powershell, pester-5

I'm using Pester version:5.3.3
and not quite sure if I do it properly. I have only one file containing the whole logic: Function.Tests.ps1.

```
BeforeAll{
 import-module .\Function.Tests.ps1 -Force
 Remove-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\testresults.xml" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

Describe "Test CreateNewTable Function" {
Push-Location
Import-Module sqlserver -DisableNameChecking
Pop-Location

$tableName = 'xxx'
$instance = "myServer"
$dbcmd = @"
SELECT [Name] AS TableName 
  FROM [sys].[tables] 
 WHERE [Name] = '$($tableName)'
"@
 $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $dbcmd `
                      -ServerInstance $instance `
                      -Database 'master' `
                      -SuppressProviderContextWarning
 It "$tableName should exist" {
   ($result.TableName -eq $tableName) | Should -Be $true
 }
}
```

When I run the test for the first time with the table "xxx" in place it's all fine and I get - as expected - a success message:

```
Invoke-Pester .\Function.Tests.ps1
```

But when I change the script putting a wrong table name, say "yyy", I was expecting an error, but nothing happens and I still get a success message.
Strangely enough when I change the server name to a wrong name, Pester reflects that change and I get an error, but changing the dbname to the wrong name brings still a success.

-- Edited
I've created a separate two files: a function and the test unit.
The function:

```
Function Get-Table
{  
param(
       [string]$tableName,
       [string]$instance,
       [string]$database
)
$dbcmd = @"
SELECT [Name] AS TableName 
  FROM [sys].[tables] 
 WHERE [Name] = '$($tableName)'
"@
return $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $dbcmd `
                      -ServerInstance $instance `
                      -Database $database `
                      -SuppressProviderContextWarning
}
```

and the test unit:

```
BeforeAll{
. $PSScriptRoot/Get-Table.ps1
}
Describe "Test CreateNewTable Function" {
Import-Module sqlserver -DisableNameChecking
$tableName = 'clusters'
$instance = "xxx"
$database = "YYY"
$result = Get-Table -tableName $tableName -instance $instance - 
database $database
# Now run the test   
It "$tableName should exist" {
    ($result.TableName -eq $tableName) | Should -Be $true
    }
}
```

Both files are in the same directory, calling the test:

```
Invoke-Pester C:\PesterTests\Function.Tests.ps1
```

I'll still get the error:

Discovery in C:\PesterTests\Function.Tests.ps1 failed with:
System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Get-Table' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function
meaning the function file will not be loaded and the function Get-Table is unknown.

Comment: In Pester 5 you are not supposed to put test code directly within `Describe`. Instead, put common code into `BeforeAll` block, see [example](https://pester.dev/docs/commands/BeforeAll#example-2). See also [Migrating from Pester v4 to v5](https://pester.dev/docs/migrations/v4-to-v5)

Comment: means: I have to create a separate file with testing the database and check it inside Function.Tests.ps1?

Comment: I did some changes, please have a look above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is as simple as that: you can't put the logic in the describe-block (as I was doing), as soon as I put the logic in "it" block it works!

```
BeforeAll {
. $PSScriptRoot/Get-Table.ps1
}
Describe 'Get-Table' {
It "$tableName should exist" {
  Push-Location
  Import-Module sqlserver -DisableNameChecking
  Pop-Location
  $tableName = 'cluster'
  $instance = "xxx"
  $database = "YYY"
  $result = Get-Table -tableName $tableName -instance $instance -database 
  $database
  $result.TableName -eq $tableName | Should -Be $true
  }
}
```